# How to deserialize individual fields from TreeNode?

Tags: java, jackson

[JsonParser.readValueAsTree()](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser.html#readValueAsTree()) returns a TreeNode, but it's not clear how to deserialize complex properties of that tree. For example, I want to deserialize a property of type `Map<String, Object>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick seems to be to use [ObjectCodec](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/ObjectCodec.html) as follows:

```
JsonParser p = ...;
ObjectCodec codec = p.getCodec();
TreeNode node = p.readValueAsTree();
Map<String, String> childToParentIds = codec.treeAsTokens(node.get("childToParent")).readValueAs(
                new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>()
            {
            });
```